# Android - Listview is only updating with Firebase values after scroll

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

ListView only updates after scrolling. 
I have a listview that has a combination of hardcoded values and firebase retrieved values. When the listview loads for first time, all hardcoded values show, but 1/2 of the firebase are values displayed. Only after scrolling down (to completely hide items) and then back up (to make items reappear), does the correct listview items show.

First picture is what it shows on fresh load and second is after you scrolled
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGydm.jpg

I tried adding the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after attaching the listview to the adapter hoping it would mimic a 'refresh' of the listview. But that didn't work.

Activity with Listview

```
package com.example.uniplan;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExploreCourses extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "ExploreCourses";
    public static ArrayList<ECCourse> courseAllList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<ECCourse> courseFavourites;
    public ListView listAll,listFav;
    public static ECCourseAdapter adapter, adapter2;
    public EditText editTextSearchBarCourses;
    public Button ecSearchButton;
    public static ArrayList<ECCourse> tempAllCourse = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_explore_courses);



        //Creating All course list
        listAll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAllCourses);
        listAll.setTag(1);

        //Creating the favourite course list
        listFav = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFavCourses);
        listFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listFav.setTag(2);

        //Buttons
        //Button Underlines
        final ImageView underline1 = findViewById(R.id.imageUnderline1);
        final ImageView underline2 = findViewById(R.id.imageUnderline2);
        underline2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        //All Button
        TextView all = findViewById(R.id.textViewAllCourses);
        all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listAll.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    listAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    listFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    underline1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    underline2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        //Saved Button
        TextView saved = findViewById(R.id.textViewSavedCourses);
        saved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listFav.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    listAll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    listFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    underline1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    underline2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });

        //Creating the initial all subject array list.
        initAllCourses();

        //Create the array for favourited courses
        courseFavourites = new ArrayList<>();
        createFavouriteCourses(courseAllList);



        //Adapter
        adapter = new ECCourseAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_explore_courses_item,courseAllList);
        adapter2 = new ECCourseAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_explore_courses_item,courseFavourites);
        listAll.setAdapter(adapter);
        listFav.setAdapter(adapter2);

        //Search Bar & Button
        editTextSearchBarCourses = findViewById(R.id.editTextSearchBarCourses);
        editTextSearchBarCourses.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        editTextSearchBarCourses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editTextSearchBarCourses.setText("");
                editTextSearchBarCourses.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });

        ecSearchButton = findViewById(R.id.ecSearchButton);

//        ecSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                //Makes backup of All courses list
//                for(ECCourse example : courseAllList){
//                    tempAllCourse.add(example.clone);
//                }
//
//
//                tempAllCourse.addAll(courseAllList);
//                courseAllList.clear();
//                String searchQuery = editTextSearchBarCourses.getText().toString();
//                for(int i = 0;i<tempAllCourse.size();i++){
//                    if(tempAllCourse.get(i).getCourseCode().matches("[A-Za-z0-9]*" +
//                            searchQuery + "[A-Za-z0-9]*")){
//                        courseAllList.add(tempAllCourse.get(i));
//                    }
//                }
//                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//            }
//        });



        //ListView All Subjects Listeners
        listAll.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ExploreCourses.this,CourseInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("CourseCode",courseAllList.get(position).getCourseCode());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //ListView Favourite Subjects Listener
        listFav.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ExploreCourses.this,CourseInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("CourseCode",courseFavourites.get(position).getCourseCode());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });





    }


    public void initAllCourses(){

        //Only runs if the array is empty.
        if(courseAllList.isEmpty()) {

            //Course Objects
            ECCourse c1 = new ECCourse("ACCT1501", "Accounting & Financial Mgt 1A", "false");
            ECCourse c2 = new ECCourse("INFS1603", "Intro to Business Databases", "true");
            ECCourse c3 = new ECCourse("INFS3605", "IS Innovation & Transformation", "false");
            ECCourse c4 = new ECCourse("MGMT1101", "Global Business Environment", "false");
            ECCourse c5 = new ECCourse("MARK1012", "Marketing Fundamentals", "false");
            ECCourse c6 = new ECCourse("ECON2209", "Business Forecasting", "false");
            ECCourse c7 = new ECCourse("ECON1101", "Microeconomics 1", "false");
            ECCourse c8 = new ECCourse("INFS1602", "Digital Transformation in Business", "false");
            ECCourse c9 = new ECCourse("INFS2605", "Intermediate Business Programming", "false");
            ECCourse c10 = new ECCourse("MATH1041", "Statistics for Life and Social Sciences", "false");
            ECCourse c11 = new ECCourse("MGMT1001", "Managing Organisations and People", "false");
            //Adding Courses to All List

            courseAllList.add(c1);
            courseAllList.add(c2);
            courseAllList.add(c3);
            courseAllList.add(c4);
            courseAllList.add(c5);
            courseAllList.add(c6);
            courseAllList.add(c7);
            courseAllList.add(c8);
            courseAllList.add(c9);
            courseAllList.add(c10);
            courseAllList.add(c11);

        }

    }

    public static void createFavouriteCourses(ArrayList<ECCourse> object){

        if(!courseFavourites.isEmpty()){
            courseFavourites.clear();
            Log.d(TAG, "createFavouriteCourses: courseFavourite Array is cleared, size: " +
                    courseFavourites.size());
        }

        if(courseFavourites.isEmpty()){

            //Goes through the all subjects list and adds the ones that are favoured into the favourite array
            Log.d(TAG, "createFavouriteCourses: size of object array (all courses)" + object.size());
            for(int i =0; i<object.size();i++){
                if (courseAllList.get(i).getCourseFav().equals("true")) {
                    courseFavourites.add(courseAllList.get(i));
                    Log.d(TAG, "createFavouriteCourses: Course added to favourites, code: " +
                            courseAllList.get(i).getCourseCode());
                }

            }
        }

        if(courseFavourites.isEmpty()){
            Log.d(TAG, "createFavouriteCourses: No courses were added");
        }



    }

    public static void clearCourseAllList(){
        if(!courseAllList.isEmpty()){
            courseAllList.clear();
        }

        //Have to add this either when user logs in or fresh user is created.
        //Already added in the fresh user section,
        //Need to add it in successful user login. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }

    public static void refreshLists(){
        //This actually only refreshes the favourite courses array, by passing the new all course array
        createFavouriteCourses(courseAllList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(ExploreCourses.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Adapter Activity

```
package com.example.uniplan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ECCourseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ECCourse> {
    private static final String TAG = "ECCourseAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    DatabaseReference mref, starRef;
    static int starCountSum, starCountAvg, reviewCount;
    ImageView RIstar5image,RIstar4image, RIstar3image, RIstar2image, RIstar1image;

    public ECCourseAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ECCourse> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //When convertView is null
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: Convert view value " + convertView);


            //Get course details.
            final String courseCode = getItem(position).getCourseCode();
            String courseName = getItem(position).getCourseName();
            String courseFav = getItem(position).getCourseFav();

            //Create course object
            ECCourse courseC = new ECCourse(courseCode, courseName, courseFav);


            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);


            TextView degreeCodeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reviewUserName);
            TextView degreeNameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reviewComment);
            final TextView ECReviewCount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ECReviewCount);
            ImageView badgeSummaryImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.badgeSummaryImage);
            final ImageView imageHeart = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageHeart);
            RIstar1image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.RIstar1image);
            RIstar2image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.RIstar2image);
            RIstar3image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.RIstar3image);
            RIstar4image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.RIstar4image);
            RIstar5image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.RIstar5image);


            degreeCodeText.setText(courseCode);
            degreeNameText.setText(courseName);


            //Review Count Setter
            mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TestCourses").child(courseCode);
            mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Running Check
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: mref.addValueEventListener Ran");
                    ECReviewCount.setText(dataSnapshot.child("reviewcount").getValue(String.class) + " Reviews");
                    int tempReviewCount = 0;
                    tempReviewCount = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("reviewcount").getValue(String.class));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: ECCourseAdapter reviewcount equals MREF " + ECCourseAdapter.reviewCount + " " + courseCode);

                    //Below are average star logic
                    Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.child("review").getChildren();
                    int tempStarCountSum = 0;

                    for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                        if (child.child("starcount").getValue(String.class) != null)
                            tempStarCountSum = tempStarCountSum + Integer.parseInt(child.child("starcount").getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: tempStarCountSum: " + tempStarCountSum + " course: " + courseCode);

                    int tempAvg = 0;

                    if (tempStarCountSum != 0 || tempReviewCount != 0) {

                        double dtempStarCountSum = (double) tempStarCountSum;
                        double dtempReviewCount = (double) tempReviewCount;

                        tempAvg = (int) Math.round(dtempStarCountSum / dtempReviewCount);
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: tempAvg equals " + tempAvg + " for course " + courseCode);

                    RIstar1image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_star);
                    RIstar2image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_star);
                    RIstar3image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_star);
                    RIstar4image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_star);
                    RIstar5image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_star);

                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: cleared stars.");

                    switch (tempAvg) {
                        //changing images
                        case 5:
                            RIstar5image.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_star);
                        case 4:
                            RIstar4image.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_star);
                        case 3:
                            RIstar3image.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_star);
                        case 2:
                            RIstar2image.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_star);
                        case 1:
                            RIstar1image.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_star);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: ran the star fillers");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Value of stars are 0 ");
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            if (courseFav.equals("true")) {
                imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_heart);
            }


            //Heart Button Handler
            imageHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Visual
                    View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
                    ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                    final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

                    final String listViewName = listView.getTag().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Heart has been clicked");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Position Number " + position);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: View it is in: " + listViewName);
                    //run a method that updates both the arrays

                    //All Section Unfilled Heart Pressed
                    if (ExploreCourses.courseAllList.get(position).getCourseFav().equals("false")
                            && listViewName.equals("1")) {
                        ExploreCourses.courseAllList.get(position).setCourseFav("true");
                        imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_heart);

                        //Reset both list views
                        ExploreCourses.refreshLists();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Heart Filled in all section");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Size of fav Array " + ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.size());
                    }
                    //All Section Filled Heart Pressed
                    else if (ExploreCourses.courseAllList.get(position).getCourseFav().equals("true")
                            && listViewName.equals("1")) {
                        ExploreCourses.courseAllList.get(position).setCourseFav("false");
                        imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_heart);

                        //Reset both list views
                        ExploreCourses.refreshLists();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Heart UNFILLED in all section");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Size of fav Array " + ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.size());

                    }

                    if (!ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.isEmpty() && listViewName.equals("2")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: courseFavourites size " + ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.size());
                        //Favourite Section filled heart
                        if (ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.get(position).getCourseFav().equals("true")) {
                            int target = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < ExploreCourses.courseAllList.size(); i++) {
                                if (ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.get(position).getCourseCode()
                                        .equals(ExploreCourses.courseAllList.get(i).getCourseCode())) {
                                    target = i;
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: target value equals " + target);
                            ExploreCourses.courseFavourites.get(position).setCourseFav("false");
                            ExploreCourses.refreshLists();


                        }
                    }

                }
            });


            return convertView;

    }

}
```

I would like it to show the second image on loadup (correct stars showing).

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: When I start the activity, the stars (check the pictures) are hollow (or uncoloured) even though I have set them to be filled in in the adapter class. It's only when I scroll down in the listview, resulting in the top listview items disappearing and rescroll up to make them reappear do the stars get properly coloured in.

Comment: There is a lot of code here, and Stack Overflow is typically a very ineffective debugger. Can you reproduce the problem with (a lot) less code? That will make it more likely that somebody can spot the problem in the remaining code. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).